# Populating column in shapefile attribute table based on row values of another column in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, attribute-table

I'm using R to manipulate an attribute table of a shapefile. The shapefile attribute table has two columns: Location ID, and Height. I want to add a third column titled "Mean", which provides the average height value by Location ID. There are over 300,000 rows in this shapefile, so this cannot be done manually.

Is there a function in R to accomplish this?

Below is an example of what the attribute table looks like. Note that the Location ID is not necessarily in sequential order; if there is an ID 1, and an ID 10, that does not mean there's an ID 2, 3, 4, etc.

```
 Location.ID Height 
          43      2 
          87      5  
          22      6  
          87      3  
          43      9  
          22      1
```

Below is the final result I am trying to achieve in R. Note that the mean values (column 3), are of height values (column 2) specific to certain Location ID values (column 1)

```
 Location.ID Height Mean
          43      2  5.5
          87      5  4.0
          22      6  3.5
          87      3  4.0
          43      9  5.5
          22      1  3.5
```

Is there a built-in function to accomplish this?

Or is there a way to iterate through row values in column 1 to populate column 3?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have a separate table with `Location.ID` and `Mean` values you would like to join to a shapefile attributes with `Location.ID` and `Height`?

Comment: No, I have a table with only Location.ID and Height. I wish to add a "Mean" column that is populated by average Height values by Location.ID

Comment: How are you generating the mean values?

Comment: I don't know, that's the problem I'm trying to figure out. I need to generate mean height values  by Location ID. You can see the ideal output in the second table of this post

Comment: It is very difficult to answer this question without a description of all the data you are working with. I am still unclear about where the mean values are coming from? It is also unclear if you are working with point or polygon data.

Comment: It is point data. The first table in the original post shows a sample of what I have; the second table what I want to turn it into. Each location (col.1) has a number ID. I want the third column to be the average height (height measurements are in col. 2)  by Location.ID. For example, note the two occurrences of Location.ID number 87. The height measurements are 5 and 3, which averages out to four. So the cell value for the new Mean Column (column 3) for both rows where Location.ID=87 is 4. I want to do this for every single Location.ID. value.

Comment: Got it now, thanks. Is it important to keep duplicates, or would you like a summary by `Location.ID`?

Comment: Once you've read the shapefile in this is not a GIS problem. If reading the shapefile in is a problem for you, ask that. Otherwise ask general R questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Aaron, yes, the mean value by Location.ID. So for Location.ID 87, the mean value would be the same throughout: 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to summarise the table then `merge` the results back to the attribute table.

If you've read in 'd' using the sf package (or rgdal, though I haven't tested that):

```
agg <- aggregate(formula = Height ~ Location.ID, data = d, FUN = mean)
d <- merge(d, agg, by = "Location.ID")
```

Comment: This worked, thank you